# reuse class object across module

Tags: python, ruby

I am trying to understand the best way to reuse an instance of a class in a module in python...

In ruby I can accomplish this by doing the following:

```
module MyMod
  def client
    @var ||= DBClient.new
  end

  def query
    client.select(...)
  end
end
```

would it be correct to assume the below is equivalent in python?

```
class Client():
    connection = DBClient()

def query():
    Client().connection.select(...)
```

In python standards would the above be ok? is there a better approach? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these things aren't the same at all. The Ruby code instantiates a connection once and assigns it to an instance var; the Python code creates a new instance of Client every time `query` is called, although they share the connection instance.

But there is no need for the added wrapper. If you want to create it once, do so at module level:

```
connection = DBClient()

def query():
    connection.select(...)
```

Really, you should stop writing Ruby in Python; if you want to write Python, you should learn how to write things idiomatically in Python, not simply translate your Ruby code directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment... This would be a second question, but might just use the thread... is there an efficient way of assuring the class is instantiated once only in python? I am guessing despite the language, we should prevent calls...

Comment: @user3087106 Look up "python singleton" on Google to find out how to instantiate a class only once.